# At user creation set different default timezone

Tags: datetime

When a new user applies for an account, how does one set the timezone default from 'America/Denver' to 'UTC' timzeone?  It's ok to allow the user to change the timezone to a preferred timezone.  However, most of my users will be signing up from the UK.  Is there a way to set the default to UTC rather than America/Denver?

Comment: r u using date module? i think there is an option to set default timezone.

Answer (score 3):

Try visiting `admin/config/regional/settings` to set default timezones.

I've also created a module called [Timezone Detect](http://drupal.org/project/timezone_detect) that will detect and set user timezones automatically using javascript.

Comment: That module that you created worked for me. Thanks a million!